# Setting up AWS Credentials in spring boot for local testing and EC2 deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am pretty new to Spring Boot. I am looking to set up my application to use my IAM role for S3 access while my project is hosted on EC2, and local credentials for when I am testing on my machine. I am using `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()` in my AmazonS3ClientBuilder, I just can't figure out where I need to set up the credentials for when I am testing locally. I was hoping to set up a configuration file for the AWS credentials that I can put in my .gitignore.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Needed to created a file called "credentials" in my root directory with the following information:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=KEY
aws_secret_access_key=SECRET
```

Obviously replace KEY and SECRET with your own.

Now `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()` can see the credentials on my machine, and will use my IAM role when running on my EC2.